# Laravel broadcast with Redis pub sub and socket io takes more than 2 seconds to deliver

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io

I am building a real time notification app in Laravel using Redis pub sub and socket io. I'm handling the queue by beanstalkd and running Laravel queue:work with supervisord. After all the successful set up it takes more or equal to 3 seconds to receive the notifications by the client.

Is it normal or can it reduced even further???

My O.S is centos 6.9 with 8 GB Ram and Quad Core Xeon E3-1220 Processor.
Php 7.0, Laravel version 5.2, Redis 3.9.103 with phpredis extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `artisan queue:work` command uses a default polling interval of three seconds:

```
$ artisan queue:work --help 

Options:
    ...
    --sleep[=SLEEP]    Number of seconds to sleep when no job is available  [default: "3"]
```

So, you can reduce this value to decrease the delay you're seeing. This only applies with an empty queue (like it probably is in development). If the queue is busy, the worker will continue to pop jobs without delay until it runs out.

Laravel added [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting) in version 5.3 that better suits real-time events like notifications than the queue.